# BadZipFile: file is not a zip file in reading excel file using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to execute the following code and I'm constantly experiencing this issue.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('First_Run.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(df.head())
```

I've make sure that excel file is there at the respective path. Have tried multiple ways to resolve the issue but failed to find the desired solution.

Here's the output of the code block.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fharookshaik\Desktop\Gmail Bot\temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel('First_Run.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper   
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel  
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1131, in __init__   
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 475, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 391, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 486, in load_workbook     
    return load_workbook(
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive      
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\fharookshaik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Hope, this will be answered soon by the brilliant minds on this dynamic community.

Thanks in well Advance.

Comment: AFAIK, `xlsx` is actually a zip file (try open it with a zip manager). In your case, most likely you have a corrupted file.

Comment: If it's not imperative that you use xlsx, try using csv instead.

Comment: Well sir, I need to access that in '.xlsx' mode only.